route namespace not apply when use action in blade
I'm starting a project with laravel v11. From v10 in blade I'm normally use action('Controller@action', ['param' => $key]) and it's working fine. Now I have to change with route('name.action', ['param' => $key])
If I use with action('App\Http\Controllers\Controller@action', ['param' => $key]) it's working
All route I define all working but have to change from action to route. But when I use action then error show up with

Action 'API\Controller@form' not defined

I'm also defined a name space in bootstrap/apps.php like this
using: function () {
    Route::middleware('api')
       ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
       ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

    Route::middleware('web')
       ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
       ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
},

